# Why am I getting an error when I try to add a Primary Key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and SSMS.

I have a table called PersonsTable:

```
   PersonID  FirstName   Surname  Age
    1         Hansen      Ola      30
    2         Svendson    Tove     23
    3         Pettersen   Kari     20
```

I am trying to set a primary key like so:

```
ALTER TABLE PersonsTable
ADD PRIMARY KEY (PersonID);
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Msg 8111, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'PersonsTable'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

Comment: pretty clear from the error , column needs to be not null

Comment: This is a case where reading the error message carefully helps you. In your `PersonsTable`  definition  put `NOT NULL` on the `PersonID` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a primary key because that column is set to allow null values. Modify the column to not allow nulls.

Via query, it should look something like:

```
alter table PersonsTable alter column PersonID INT not null
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where reading the error message carefully helps you. In your `PersonsTable`  definition  put `NOT NULL` on the `PersonID` column.

And, you don't need to create a primary key to build a relationship between tables. If you want to enforce the relationship, use foreign keys. It's hard to be more specific because you didn't show your table definitions.